# Where To Put User-defined Classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, user-defined

I'm trying to to use this class

http://robbyonrails.com/articles/2005/05/11/parsing-a-rss-feed

but am not sure where to place the file so that it functions like a helper.

Comment: Yes! I found Travis' solution you posted to do what I needed to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where To Put User-defined Classes in Rails ? To **lib** directory

---

To your specific RssReader class question.

The best code written on that page is in comment from Veez (30.7.2008). Final code should look like this (not tested)

```
# lib/rss_reader.rb
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'

class RssReader

  def self.posts_for(feed_url, length=2, perform_validation=false)
    posts = []
    open(feed_url) do |rss|
      posts = RSS::Parser.parse(rss, perform_validation).items
    end
    posts[0..length - 1] if posts.size > length
  end
```

In controller

```
# for last five messages
require 'rss_reader'
def some_action
  @posts = RssReader.posts_for(rss_url, 5, false)
end
```

In view (rewritten from comment in HAML to ERB)

```
<ul>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li><%= post.title %> - <%= post.description %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Watch [RSS::Parser.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rss/rdoc/classes/RSS/Parser.html#M003310) parameters for details.

---

*I think, rss feed reader should be Model in Rails. Very simple RSS feed reader is described by [Travis on Rails](http://travisonrails.com/2007/06/09/Parsing-an-RSS-Feed-with-Ruby) (read comments, you don't need to use open method).*